# Are EventListeners automatically added to the AWTEventMulticaster in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

We are seeing a StackOverflow error in our application after numerous `JTextFields` are instantiated in the application.    The error, shown below, involves the `AWTEventMulticaster`.   Based on my reading of what this is, I don't understand how this could be happenning since we never explicitly add event listerners to the `AWTEventMulticaster` (until now we didn't know it existed).   When we attach a listener to a component, is it somehow automatically registered with the `AWTEventMulticaster` as well?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.removeInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Code? May be you are adding a listener inside listener or some other stuff  doing recursion unknowingly ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Java Doc...

> AWTEventMulticaster implements efficient and thread-safe multi-cast event
>   dispatching for the AWT events defined in the java.awt.event package.

So if you look at the stack, method remove and removeInternal is being called again and again. This indicates that something is calling method remove. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNhUb.jpg][1]][1]. I suspect one of your code piece which is creating random JTextField's is a problem source. Are you removing components from your panels? 
Still you can look at the following points.

1. Check if there is any keylistener/ActionListener/MouseListener registered to the components which you are stacking again and again.
2. Check if there is any repetitive component removal from your respective panels, this can cause number of internal or external events stacked into AWTEventMultiCaster. Remember there are events trigger for every component added to the panel.
3. If you look at the call hierarchy of the java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.remove so a property change happening inside a loop can cause this issue.
4. Last but not least, make sure you update UI outside the loop. updateUI or updateComponentTree like methods must be kept outside the loops. 
   A viewport update can also be a potential issue.

Please let me know if this helps. Or send code snippet which exactly is causing the issue.